# Linking C# files between pages in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, windows-phone

Hello I am very new to Visual Studio and am trying to develop Windows Phone applications.

I have created a main pivot page for my application called MainPage.xaml and then from there I have an application bar which has a few buttons on it, one called settings which leads to a Settings.xaml page. Both of these xaml pages have their respective C# pages. The problem is when I create variables in one of the C# pages they do not appear in the other C# page, as in Intellisense doesnt recognise them and they are just underlined in red indicating an error. How do I get the C# pages to talk to and recognise each other?

For example if I am in the settings C# page and I have a textbox that a user can store information into and that information is stored under the variable `text`, how would my MainPage C# file be able to see that varibale and use it, because at the moment it can't.

Comment: Have you considered using MVVM patterns (and frameworks ?).

Answer (score 0):

Each XAML page you create is unique class. The same rules applies: You cannot have access to variables on the pages, if you don’t have reference or they are static. 
So two possible solutions for you:

1. Make variables you want to access statics
2. Pass a reference to the object during the call

Edit: For your example use one of these two:

1. Delegates
2. Local storage to save settings

Edit 2: you should use “mainviewmodel” (MVVM) to change informations too. See the default Windows Phone project for example

Answer (score 0):

you can send parameter when you navigate between pages.

```
Frame.Navigate(TypeName, Object)
```

example

```
int myVariable = 6;
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SettingPage), myVariable);
```

You can receive the variable that you have sent in this override method of the page

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    int myVariable = (int)e.Parameter;
}
```

---

But in this case. saving settings and then load in the app. I will use

```
Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings
```

to store settings value that can access from everywhere in the app

save settings

```
var settings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
settings.Values["myVariable"] = 6;
```

load settings

```
var settings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
int myVariable = (int)settings.Values["myVariable"];
```

[Local app data (Windows Runtime apps using C#/VB/C++ and XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One of the way is this:

Steps
**Settings.xaml.cs**

1. Create a public property

   ```
   // FIRST TYPE
   public string TextBoxValue
   {
       get; set;
   }

   or

   // SECOND TYPE
   public static string TextBoxValue
   {
       get; set;
   }
   ```
2. Set value of TextBoxValue Property to your textbox value.

   ```
   TextBoxValue = MyTextbox.Text; //MyTextbox is the xaml control.
   ```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

For FIRST TYPE Property, create object of setting class and refer TextBoxValue.

```
    Settings st = new Settings();
    var value = st.TextBoxValue;
```

or

For SECOND TYPE Property,

```
      var value = Settings.TextBoxValue;
```

Comment: This looks promising however can you please provide an example of assigning a value in the Settings.xaml.cs with the get and set statements and then importing that value into the MainPage.xaml.cs as I am not very experienced with objects.